# How do I retrieve individual header field values in PHP after retrieving the header string with CURL?

Tags: php, regex, curl, http-headers, preg-match

I am using CURL to execute HTTP requests.  I get back something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2011 15:52:33 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

My question is, how can I reliably retrieve any of the four named fields' values?

Right now I am doing this:

```
$name = 'Expires';
preg_match('/^'.$name.': ([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]*$/m', $headers, $matches);
```

It seems to be working.  I'm just curious of my regular expression here is going to work for every well-formed header I ever receive from a server, or if there are variances where it would break.  I can't seem to find specific restrictions on valid characters, newlines or carriage returns so I don't know if all values will follow the format:

Fieldname followed by colon, followed by space, followed by non-newline characters, followed by newline characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a way it could break. Although, if you know that the order is always the same, then there is no need to include the variable name in the regexp, just start with a semicolon. Then, you could just simplify it to

```
/:(.*)$/m
```

the `$` should stop right at the end of the line, and `(.*)` will cause that you will have the variable value included in the specified group. As you know there should be 4 groups, in the case above.

Comment: For some reason then I use the 'm' modifier it still leaves me with a single \n at the end of the matched string.

Comment: I mean it leaves a single \r at the end.

Comment: The only way I may test it now is via http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ or some other online regexp tool. However, if you really do not want to match `\r` nor `\n` then probably this slight modification of your regexp will best suit your needs `'/:\s([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]?$/m'`

Answer (score 1):

PHP has its built-in way of doing this with http_parse_headers(), which has got to be a better way to go than rolling your own.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php

Comment: requires pecl_http unfortunately

Comment: and available only in linux

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and don't have problems so far (far from ideal of course):

```
// $this->headers contains string with all headers
private function parseHeaders()
{
    $headers = array();
    foreach (explode("\n", $this->headers) as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (strpos($line, ':') !== false) {
            list($headerName, $headerValue) = explode(':', $line, 2);
            $headerValue = ltrim($headerValue);
            $headerName = strtolower(rtrim($headerName));
            if (isset($headers[$headerName])) {
                if (is_array($headers[$headerName])) {
                    $headers[$headerName][] = $headerValue;
                } else {
                    $headers[$headerName] = array(
                        $headers[$headerName],
                        $headerValue
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $headers[$headerName] = $headerValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

However, if you want to do it in most correct way, I think you should read [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)